# Object Not Duplicating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D rouge like game inspired by the binding of isaac. I have a bullet off screen that gets duplicated to make bullets shoot. I used instinate to do this but it doesn't duplicate.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletspeed;
    public float bulletdelay;
    private float lastFire; 

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        float shootHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Shoot Sideways");
        float shootVertical = Input.GetAxis("Shoot Up");

        if((shootHorizontal != 0 || shootVertical != 0) && Time.time > lastFire + bulletdelay)
        {
            Shoot(shootHorizontal, shootVertical);
            lastFire = Time.time;
        }

        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, vertical * speed);
    }

    void Shoot(float x, float y)
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        bullet.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0;
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(
                (x < 0) ? Mathf.Floor(x) * bulletspeed : Mathf.Ceil(x) * bulletspeed,
                (y < 0) ? Mathf.Floor(y) * bulletspeed : Mathf.Ceil(y) * bulletspeed,
                0
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not duplicating? What you expect from this behavior to do? It will just spawn new bullet and it is assigned with properties. If you `Shoot()` again, it will create new bullet.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved It literally just doesn't make a new bullet it's not invisible and I know that because It doesnt't appear in the hierarchy

Comment: Try to use method with `Parent` -> `Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation, this.transform)` as shown in [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). That way the bullet should be generated just under your player. Also make a break point and debug this - to see whether this line is even "executed".

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Still doesn't duplicate it

Comment: Try debug it ... e.g. by following some tutorial - [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt2YdrUlzgg).

Comment: You should avoid instantiating per frame as it's a severe drain on performance, instead use object pooling: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be that the bulletPrefab is not assigned in the Inspector. Make sure that you have assigned the bullet prefab to the bulletPrefab variable in the Inspector.

Another possible issue could be that the Shoot function is not being called. You can add a Debug.Log statement inside the Shoot function to check if it’s being called.